# Bootstrap 3: How to make margins responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on the header of a website right now and I have a UL list with an special alignment using the "margin-left" css property.

The problem is that when I start scaling down that margin doesn't. It just behaves like an element that is colliding with the nav-brand and therefore the UL list stacks below the nav-brand.

I want to make that margin responsive, so it scales accordingly and it preserves the same relative distance to the nav-brand.

I can't rely on the CSS3 @media functionality because I need this to be fluid and responsive for several devices.

Any idea on how to create responsive margins?

```
<div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/Logo.png" style="width: 150px;" ></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:550px;">
   <li><a href="">Documentation</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Dev. Login</a></li>   
   <li><a href="">Get Started</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use percentage based margins? You can also alter them at different screen widths using media queries. If you add some code and/or a demo to your question then it would be easier to give you more specific advice.

Comment: Erm how about the same way bootstrap does the rest of things, specify different variations in each of the @media sections?

Comment: yes. I agree with the @media solution but I need something more fluid than that.

Comment: @user3381594 - I don't quite understand why media queries are unsuitable as what you're describing is the use case they were created for. Also, percentage based values are fluid. Why not remove the fixed, pixel-based margin and just add `ul.navbar-nav{ float: right; }` to override bootstrap's default `float: left;`?

Comment: The problem with using "float: right" is that it doesn't align the element in the exact position I want. That's why I'm using the margin. I would like to find something more fluid than the media break points.  Maybe I'm taking it too far pixel perfection wise, but I'm curious to know if there's something like a responsive margin at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into flexbox. it makes easy work of many layouts that are difficult otherwise -- it's shaping up to be the standard web layout tool for the very near future.

Acording to [Solved by Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/) browser support is Chrome 21+, Firefox 22+, Safari 6.1+ and IE 11+ . If you need wider IE support you could use conditional comments to load custom CSS for IE<11 which could give a provide as good an experience as possible.

That site has some good examples, as does [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you'll find plenty of others as well.

Good luck!